# created L-shaped background

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, shapes

I am trying to create an L-shaped background: a background with an underline and a left line. For further reference, it is similar to one of android's design for EditText. I need to place such a background for an AutocompleteTextview. In any case, here is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@color/transparent" >
            </solid>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="line" >
            <solid android:color="#000000" >
            </solid>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="90"
            android:toDegrees="90" >
            <shape android:shape="line" >
                <stroke android:color="#000000" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

but when I try to apply the shape to my autocompleteTextView as

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
  ...  
    android:background="@drawable/autocompletetextview_bkg"
/>
```

the `Graphical Layout` in eclipse has a `java.lang.NullPointerException`. can you see what's wrong with the shape file?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.graphics.Canvas.drawLine(Canvas.java:931)
at android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable.draw(GradientDrawable.java:538)
at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.draw(LayerDrawable.java:349)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14450)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14350)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14468)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14350)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14348)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14468)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14350)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14468)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.render(RenderSessionImpl.java:584)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:338)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:332)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:504)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.renderWithBridge(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1584)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.recomputeLayout(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1309)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.activated(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1066)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.LayoutEditorDelegate.delegatePageChange(LayoutEditorDelegate.java:686)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.common.CommonXmlEditor.pageChange(CommonXmlEditor.java:360)
at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart$2.widgetSelected(MultiPageEditorPart.java:292)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4166)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1466)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1489)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1474)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1279)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.setSelection(CTabFolder.java:3080)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.onMouse(CTabFolder.java:1772)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder$1.handleEvent(CTabFolder.java:279)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4166)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1466)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1489)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1474)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1279)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4012)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3651)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:140)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:611)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
```

Comment: In case it matters: `android:minSdkVersion="11"`

Answer (score 0):

Change the middle item to

```
<shape android:shape="line" >
    <stroke android:color="#000000" />
</shape>
```

Rule of thumb: `line` shaped drawables don't have a body (they're very thin) so they can't have a solid color.