# Android recycler view divideritem 4.4 compatibility

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm having this exception while rendering the divider items in a recyclerview only for android 4.4, its working finein android 5.0

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.view.GLES20Canvas.setupModifiers(GLES20Canvas.java:1439)
        at android.view.GLES20Canvas.drawLines(GLES20Canvas.java:1019)
        at android.view.GLES20Canvas.drawLine(GLES20Canvas.java:1009)
        at android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable.draw(GradientDrawable.java:538)
        at com.sistac.informecampos.fragments.DividerItemDecoration.onDrawOver(DividerItemDecoration.java:35)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.draw(RecyclerView.java:2444)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13362)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14182)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
        at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.drawChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1040)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13357)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14182)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13357)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14182)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13357)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14182)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
        at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.drawChild(DrawerLayout.java:1229)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13357)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14182)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14468)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:472)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13362)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14182)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13357)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14182)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13357)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14182)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14468)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13362)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14182)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14468)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:472)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2326)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13362)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
        at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.buildDisplayList(HardwareRenderer.java:1570)
        at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:1449)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2377)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2249)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1879)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:996)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:
```

My DividerItem implementation overrides

```
 @Override
public void onDrawOver(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
    int left = parent.getPaddingLeft();
    int right = parent.getWidth() - parent.getPaddingRight();

    int childCount = parent.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        View child = parent.getChildAt(i);

        RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();

        int top = child.getBottom() + params.bottomMargin;
        int bottom = top + mDivider.getIntrinsicHeight();

        mDivider.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
        mDivider.draw(c);
    }

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/grid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<include layout="@layout/new_fab" />
```

its pretty simple. Is there any suggested steps to identify and fix these kind of errors?

Thanks,
Jorge

Comment: This post helped me to fix the issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23637267/created-l-shaped-background

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This helped to me: change divider xml from

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="line">
    <solid android:color="#00000000"/>
    <size android:height="1dp"/>
</shape>
```

to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="line">
    <stroke android:color="#00000000"/>
    <size android:height="1dp"/>
</shape>
```

changed **solid** to **stroke**

Comment: changed solid to stroke

Comment: I never would have figured this out on my own.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, some necessary attributes for the shape were missing.
In my own case I had to add **stroke** attribute which was missing:

```
<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="@color/transparent"
    />
```